# can't deserialize an Object to its original Type using jackson @JsonTypeInfo annotation

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

im Trying to serialize an object ( from an Enum ) in the client-side of my application and deserialize it in the other side ( server-side ) to the same Object using jackson . i have this enum in my client-side :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
public enum Request{
    Signup,
    Login
}
```

which using the @jsonTypeInfo annotaion of jackson .

and on the server-side im doing this to deserialize the object :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode jsonNode;
    jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);  //json is the return String from the convertObjectToJson(Request.Signup);

    //i get the error on this line
    String type = jsonNode.get("@type").asText();
```

as i've commented in the code above im getting the NullException on the `jsonNode.get("@type").asText()` while the json is : `[ "Request", "Signup" ]`

and this is the function that serialize the objects :

```
public static String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(object);
        return json;
    }
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson by default will represent java enums as simple strings and for that reason you are unable to deserialize the object

Take a look here, it could help: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums